# Creating percentile_cont as aggregate function in Vertica

Tags: aggregate-functions, vertica

I need an aggregate function for percentile_cont() in Vertica. However, only analytic function for it is available in this database.

Is it possible to create one using stored procedure or something? Will really appreciate any advice and steps to construct this.

Ideally, it should work like Oracle's aggregate percentile_cont() as shown in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions110.htm).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Analytical function still if you want to and just inline view or use `with`. As long as the grouping is the same as your partition, the pc_value will always be the same for that group level (as in, safe to group on).

```
select g1, g2, pc_value, sum(value) sum_value
from ( 
    select g1, g2, value, PERCENTILE_CONT(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY g1, g2)
) x
group by g1, g2, pc_value
```

You can try to create a UDX (although it won't look exactly like this because of the language construct, so you'd probably create a function with two parameters)... but I really don't think it'll perform better and this isn't too unreadable.